# Sticky header/footer in a resizable container

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to make the header and footer fixed at the top and bottom portion of a resizable container. However, when I resize the container the footer stays fixed and doesn't respond with its container.

Here is my code:

```
    <script>
      $(function() {
        $( "#resizable" ).resizable();
      });
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
        .container {
            height: 500px;
            width: 500px;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }

        #sticky-header, #sticky-footer {
            position: relative;
            min-height: 100px!important;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: black;
        }

        #sticky-header {
            top: 0;
        }

        #main {
            min-height: 300px!important;
            width: 100%;
            overflow: scroll;
        }

        #sticky-footer {
            bottom: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container" id="resizable">
        <div id="sticky-header"></div>
        <div id="main"></div>
        <div id="sticky-footer"></div>
    </div><!-- /end container -->

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure what you expect, but CSS on its own should do this via `flex` and `resize` : *[demo](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/xOddLj) or snippet**s** below*

```css
.container {
  margin: auto;
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
  /* to trigger resize handle */
}
#sticky-header,
#sticky-footer {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}
#main {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="resizable">
  <div id="sticky-header">height from content</div>
  <div id="main">scroll when needed</div>
  <div id="sticky-footer">height from content</div>
</div>
```

the same with more content

```css
.container {
  margin: auto;
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}
#sticky-header,
#sticky-footer , nav a{
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  text-align:center;
}
#main {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="resizable">
  <div id="sticky-header">
    <h1>HTML Ipsum Presents</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="main">
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
      Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus
      lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor,
      facilisis luctus, metus</p>
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
      Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus
      lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor,
      facilisis luctus, metus</p>
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
      Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus
      lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor,
      facilisis luctus, metus</p>
  </div>
  <div id="sticky-footer">
    <nav>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#">Clients</a>
      <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is awesome. Using flex without resize: both and including .resizable() with jQuery UI did exactly what I needed it to! Thank you!